# custom authen backend make me can't use admin page in django

Tags: django, authentication, admin

I can't login to admin page.  After I delete this below statement in setting.py , I can log in as usual.

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'chula.models.MyCustomBackend',
)

this is the source that this authen backend come from
http://www.djangorocks.com/tutorials/creating-a-custom-authentication-backend/creating-the-imap-authentication-backend.html

I want to use both  this authen bakend  and admin page. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` should contain **all** the authentication backends to use.
So if you want to use the default backend as well as the custom one you should specify both of them:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'chula.models.MyCustomBackend',
)
```

See the documentation on [Specifying authentication backends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-authentication-backends) for more details.